# export data from outlook to specific sheet in specific file

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

After a day of playing around and with a LOT of help from  **David Zemens**, I finally got this code to work in Outlook VBA. Problem: It exports the data I want it to export, but always to a new workbook. It opens the right file (C:\Users\George\Desktop\gs.xlsx) but the data goes to a new file. I would ask David but he has helped me (and taught me) so much that I don't want to over do it.
So, here is the code:

```
      Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
      'Excel objects
      Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
      Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
      Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

      MsgBox "Mail received!"


      Dim id As Variant  'used to iterate the EntryIDCollection
      Dim email As Outlook.MailItem  'represents each email item
      Dim msgText As Variant 'Array used to iterate the "lines" in the email:

      'Create an instance of Excel that we can use:
      Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
       xlApp.Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Users\George\Desktop\gs.xlsx", AddTOMRU:=False,                                                        UpdateLinks:=False


           For Each id In Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
          'Assign a mailItem variable to this email:
      Set email = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(id)

          'Add some logic to ensure you only process the right emails.
          ' you could use a defined subject and/or sender name, etc.
          ' MODIFY AS NEEDED
          If email.Subject = "Report of Property" Then
           Dim line As Variant
```

from here on is where I think I'm doing a mistake:

```
               Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
               Set xlSheet = xlWB.Worksheets(1)
               line = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Offset(1).Row '//


              For Each line In Split(email.Body, vbCrLf)
                    If Left(line, 5) = "Name:" Then
                        xlSheet.Range("B6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 6))
                    ElseIf Left(line, 13) = "Time started:" Then
                        xlSheet.Range("A6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 22))
                    ElseIf Left(line, 4) = "Sage" Then
                        xlSheet.Range("D6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 9))
                    ElseIf Left(line, 8) = "Complete" Then
                        xlSheet.Range("F6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 20))
                    ElseIf Left(line, 4) = "Job1" Then
                        xlSheet.Range("G6").Value = Trim(Mid(line, 6))
                    MsgBox "All Values have been added! Now get to work!"

                    End If
               Next


           Else
      MsgBox "Not Written"
           End If
           xlApp.Visible = True
       Next
       End Sub
```

This code opens the gs.xlsx file but puts the data in another new excel file and not the gs sheet from the gs.xlsx file. I don't know where I'm going wrong. I'm a newbie to VBA and, if not for help, I'd be still scratching my head.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your code:

```
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
```

creates a new workbook and adds it to the existing workbooks collection. Then your code uses it to do its stuff, which is why you're always manipulating that newly added workbook and not the one you previously opened.

What you need to do instead is remove that line and assign `xlWB` to your opened workbook, like this (**note** the addition of **parentheses** around the `Open` function's parameters!):

```
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\George\Desktop\gs.xlsx", AddTOMRU:=False, UpdateLinks:=False)
```

Then, when your code uses `xlWB`, it will use the workbook you opened as you intended. Before, your code was opening the workbook you wanted but it did nothing with it, since you hadn't assigned a "handle" to it in order to access it.

Comment: HI djikay! I pasted your code but it says : compilation error and sintax error. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user3758228: See my edit. You need parentheses around the `Workbooks.Open` parameters.